# Is there a patch for SA-CORE-2018-002?

Tags: 6

How can I apply patch for my Drupal 6 site which is working quite fine until now?

I've checked the patch in Drupal 7. It's using `sanitize()`. How do I add it in Drupal 6?

At the same time I'm working to have it upgraded to Drupal 8.

Comment: "This issue also affects Drupal 6. Drupal 6 is End of Life. For more information on Drupal 6 support please contact a D6LTS vendor." https://www.drupal.org/project/d6lts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the official the [FAQ about SA-CORE-2018-002](https://groups.drupal.org/security/faq-2018-002):

> **I manage a Drupal 6 site, is a fix available?**
>
> Yes, Drupal 6 is also affected and the [Drupal 6 Long Term Support](https://www.drupal.org/project/d6lts) project has patches available.

The issue for this is [[core] Add D6LTS patch for SA-CORE-2018-002](https://www.drupal.org/project/d6lts/issues/2955130).  The issue has a patch from a [security team member](https://www.drupal.org/u/dsnopek) and further information.

**2018-03-30 update:**

Per a [security team member](https://www.drupal.org/user/49851) in a [recent comment](https://groups.drupal.org/security/faq-2018-002#comment-1157321):

> Please just upgrade Drupal core rather than patching!
>
> Note also the D6lts patch and corresponding github releases for that
>   and Pressflow 6 were updated to fix a subtle flaw in the released
>   security fix that was affecting a couple contrib modules including
>   Organic Groups (og) for Drupal 6.
>
> https://github.com/d6lts/drupal/releases/tag/6.43
>
> https://github.com/pressflow/6/releases/tag/pressflow-6.43.124

Comment: There is also a D5 version of that patch in that issue.